# Type script: extract array in object

Tags: typescript

I have object as below.

```
{ id: 1, property: [2,3] }
```

How could I change to

```
[ { id: 1, property: 2 }, { id: 1, property: 3 } ]
```

Comment: According to SO rules, you need to show people what have you tried.. Apart from that, you need to use `Array.prototype.reduce` to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [ { id: 1, property: [2,3] } ];

const output = [];

input.forEach(obj => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj.property)) {
        obj.property.forEach(property => output.push({...obj, property}));
    } else {
        output.push(obj);
    }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `map` method, you map each item to another item

Here you take the `id` from each item and the value at `index` in the `property` array

```js
const input = [ { id: 1, property: [2,3] } ];

const result = input[0].property.map((value, index) => ({
  id: input[0].id,
  property: value
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

if the input is an array of elements
you may use nested  `map` and `flat`

```js
const x = [
  {id: 1, property: [2, 3]},
  {id: 3, property: [5, 6]},
];
const result = x.map(item => item.property.map(prob => ({id: item.id, property: prob}))).flat();
console.log(result)
```